# jquery cannot recognize a variable from server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

Let's say I create json string on server by function , which is lunched only if there was post request from client. The string is getting full, but from some reason when I try to access this variable from jquery it is not even null but shows like there is nothing exist to this variable.
For example:

file.cshtml:

```
var json = "";
var somthingElse = "somthing";

.....

(isPost)

{

....
var nodeid = Request["nodeid"];
json = createJson(nodeid , ....);
//the function works, json is getting full
}
```

jquery in script tag:

```
<script async>
$.post({ url: '...', data: { date: ...., nodeid: $(e).closest('....').data("nodeid")

var myJson =  @json; // => empty, noting exist, not even empty string, breaks my jquery
var mySomethingElse = @somthingElse; // => exist, full of text
```

What might be the reason?
It recognizes other variables from server side by using @

Comment: `var myJson =  "@json";`

Comment: Are your `$.post` and `var myJson = @json;` *both* in the same `script` tag?   `@variable` will only be set when the razor is generated.   If your `$.post` is returning html (via razor/partialview) then it would be rendered and have a value, in that `success:function(result)` `result` value, as part of the html.    Impossible to tell what your post/action does or what you do with the result.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same script tag,

Comment: The post is sending nodeid and other data, that is not exist on server, thats wh I have to send them and create the json with the other data that exist only on server.